# Outlook 365 (web) and Gmail (desktop) not recognizing valign bottom code in td cell

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, valign

I'm having some display issues with Outlook 365 (web version) and Gmail (desktop version). Neither mail client will recognize the valign code. All the other email clients display as intended. Below is a screenshot of how the alignment should display.

[Correct alignment of menu text links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J58oK.jpg)

The next screenshot shows how Outlook 365 (web) and Gmail (desktop) are displaying. Notice how the text links are residing in the center of the td cell instead of at the bottom as intended.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzCA0.jpg)

The current code for the background image, table set up and header area are provided at the bottom of this post.

(BTW...Litmus also displays the alignment issue, but Dreamweaver shows as intended. All major browsers and other email clients are displaying as intended. )

If anyone can review the code pasted below and see what I'm missing, it would be much appreciated. I've tried all the usual adjustments and nothing seems to accommodate Outlook 365 and Gmail desktop. Thank you to all for your quick response and expertise.

Alex

```
<div style="background-color: #00adef;"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
<v:fill type="tile" src="https://BackgroundTileURLHere" color="#e9f8f8"/>
/v:background
<![endif]-->
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody width="640px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" background="BackgroundTileURLHere" valign="top">
<table style="width: 100%;" background="BackgroundTileURLHere">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<!-- HEADER -->
<table font-family:="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" style="width: 640px;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" style="width: 640px;"><img alt="EmailHeaderTopSpacer" src="EMailHeaderTopSpacingImageFileURLHere" style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 20px; border-style: none;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 193px;"><a href="CompanyHomePageURLHere" target="_blank"><img alt="CompanyLogo" src="CompanygoFileURLHere" style="display: block; width: 193px; height: 58px; border-style: none;" /></a></td>
<td style="width: 65px;"><img alt="CompanyLogoBreathingSpaceImageFile" src="CompanyLogoBreathingSpaceImageFileURLHere" style="display: block; width: 65px; height: 58px; border-style: none;" /></td>
<td style="width: 102px;" valign="bottom"><p><a href="ClickDestinationURLHere" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #14552c; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Kelly Kettles</span></a></p></td>
<td style="width: 120px;" valign="bottom"><p style="text-align:center;"><a href="ClickDestinationURLHere" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #14552c; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Ultimate Kits</span></a></p></td>
<td style="width: 115px;" valign="bottom"><p style="text-align:center;"><a href="ClickDestinationURLHere" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #14552c; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Accessories</span></a></p></td>
<td style="width: 45px;" valign="bottom"><p style="text-align:right;"><a href="ClickDestinationURLHere" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #14552c; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: right !important;">Blog</span></a></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" style="width: 640px;"><img alt="HeaderBottomSpaceImageFile" src="HeaderBottomSpaceImageFileURLHere" style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 10px;" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll just leave it here ;) http://i.imgur.com/UFVpoId.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `valign="bottom"` with `style="vertical-align: bottom"` should work according to this source: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/